# LLVM Clang doesn't find Windows.h

Tags: c++, clang

> > Platform: Windows 10 x64,
> > IDE: text editor

Hello everyone. I am trying to compile a simple code using the Clang compiler, the problem is that when I include the 'Windows.h' header file, Clang cannot compile the code.
To compile, I use this command: `clang++ main.cpp -o test.exe`
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
cout << GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) << endl;
return 0;
}
```

However, when I use the mingw compiler, the code compiles correctly. Visual Studio versions '17 and '19 are installed on the systems. I get errors like this when compiling:

```
main-a354a4.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetSystemMetrics referenced in 
function main
test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1120 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So how to compile this code using Clang?

Comment: The problem is not with the compiler but with the linker. The `<Windows.h>` file *is* being read (properly) or you wouldn't get the `__imp__` prefix in the error message. Not being familiar with the clang++ command line, however, I don't know how to add `user32.lib` to the link library list. Can you use `#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")`?

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks, using #pragma comment (lib, "user32.lib") solves the problem, but I'm just wondering if there is any other way to solve my problem

Comment: Yeah - add `user32.lib` to the linker's inputs. But, like I said, I don't know how to do that for your version of clang++.